# How to make an histogram with a data frame

Tags: r

I was trying to make an histogram of the frequencies of a name list, the list is like this:

```
> x[1:15,]
    X                             x
1   1   JUAN DOMINGOGONZALEZDELGADO
2   2   FRANCISCO JAVIERVELARAMIREZ
3   3        JUAN CARLOSPEREZMEDINA
4   4         ARMANDOSALINASSALINAS
5   5   JOSE FELIXZAMBRANOAMEZQUITA
6   6           GABRIELMONTIELRIVAS
7   7       DONACIANOSANCHEZHERRERA
8   8            JUAN MARTINXHUERTA
9   9 ALVARO ALEJANDROGONZALEZRAMOS
10 10     OMAR ROMANCASTAÑEDALOPEZ 
11 11              IGNACIOBUENOCANO
12 12       RAFAELBETANCOURTDELGADO
13 13  LUIS ALBERTOCASTILLOESCOBEDO
14 14       VICTORHERNANDEZGONZALEZ
15 15              FATIMAROMOTORRES
```

in order to do that I change it to a frequency table, it looks like this:

```
> y[1:15,]
    X                                                                   x Freq
1   1                                                                       15
2   2                                             JULIO CESAR ORDAZFLORES    1
3   3                                         MARCOS ANTONIOCUEVASNAVARRO    1
4   4       DULEY DILTON                               TRIBOUILLIERLOARCA    1
5   5                                                 ANTONIORAMIREZLOPEZ    2
6   6                                        BRAYAN ALEJANDROOJEDARAMIREZ    1
7   7                                           JOSE DE JESUSESCOTOCORTEZ    1
8   8                                                   AARONFLORESGARCIA    1
9   9                                                ABIGAILNAVARROAMBRIZ    1
10 10                                              ABILENYRODRIGUEZORTEGA    1
11 11                                             ABRAHAMHERNANDEZRAMIREZ    1
12 12                                               ABRAHAMPONCEALCANTARA    1
13 13                                          ADRIAN VAZQUEZ BUSTAMANTE     2
14 14                                             ADRIANHERNANDEZBERMUDEZ   28
15 15                                           ALAN ORLANDOCASTILLALOPEZ   11
```

when I try `hist(x)` or `hist(x[,2])` I get:

```
Error in hist.default(x) : 'x' must be numeric
```

and if I try `hist(y[,3])` I got an strange histogram which is not the desired, now how can I make a histogram of the frequencies of the name list?

Comment: https://keydifferences.com/difference-between-histogram-and-bar-graph.html. Can you confirm you want a historgram. I think since your x values are likely categorical (the names), a barchart is more suitable

Comment: i made the boxplot but the original data is about 1.2 millions of entries, i would like to see the distribution of the reincidences in the name list, did i explain myself? thank u for reading

Comment: barplot(y$Freq, names.arg = y$x) how does that work for you? This is not the most efficient way to make the plot

Comment: You want a histogram of the frequencies of the name list, and your `hist(y[,3])` is the best way to do that. What exactly is undesirable about it? If there's something more required then can you please elaborate on that.

Comment: the barplot works perfect! thank u so much!